# How to boot Windows XP (no GRUB menu is shown)?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-xp

I installed ubuntu 12.04 alongwith with Windows XP. But the system directly boots Ubuntu without giving grub selection menu. I opened a terminal up (ctrl-alt-t) and typed in the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Then my password and followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

But i got the message as follows:

```
BuildiReading package lists... Doneng dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot
E: Unable to locate package repair
```

So now what should I do? Please help as I cannot access Windows XP...

Comment: try `sudo update-grub`, this will identify Xp i guess. And this is wrong way of using apt-get `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`, it should be only `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`

Comment: Please run `sudo os-prober` in the terminal and post the output (if any). If it produces no output, then please also run boot info script: http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ and post the RESULTS.txt which it produces.

Comment: after typing sudo update-grub i got the following message:

Comment: after following instructions on sourceforge.net and entering the said command in terminal i got the message...                      bash: /home/ashwin/Desktop/boot_info_script.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Since your Downloads directory is probably ~/Downloads/ try running `sudo bash ~/Downloads/boot_info_script.sh`. I assume that since you're trying to run boot info script, `sudo os-prober` produced no output. Is that correct?

Comment: @tijybba I typed sudo update-grub and got the following message:   Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done

Comment: From Ubuntu , browse all the partitions present and Verify that XP installation *(Program files, windows)* is present.And if it is present then from the above downloaded `boot_info_script.sh` file , just run it , and it will generate text file post its contents here.

Comment: Also after typing **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update** , did you pressed ENTER to add it , did that method completed.

Comment: after completing the boot repair(recommended) i got the following link:----paste.ubuntu.com/1091318

Answer (score 2):

You typed the Wrong syntax of [Apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) command,

It should have been

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Alternately you can make your Xp detected by grub through

```
sudo update-grub
```

**EDIT :** You didn't mentioned presence of second Hard Drive as can be seen from [paste.ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1091318/) , as **sdb**.

My guess as [Jordan Uggla](https://askubuntu.com/users/6618/jordan-uggla) said , Windows XP is not present , i think you installed Ubuntu over XP installation thereby erasing it .

If you think `Xp` is still present , then try searching for the `Windows system folder` and please post the Whereabouts of its location from your Drive  in your question by editing it , probably as its partition number.

Answer (score 1):

This one helped me. Especially the section for older LCD

"/etc/default/grub and uncommenting / removing the #hash from what appears as line 364 in the boot info script as #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480"

Link:
[Why is Grub menu not shown when starting my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182248/why-is-grub-menu-not-shown-when-starting-my-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Also try installing this harmless little package: `extlinux` -- sometimes it causes an os-probe which succeeds in finding Windows when regular `update-grub` does not.

```
sudo apt-get install extlinux
```

You can remove it if it works and Windows shows up in the Grub boot menu.

Comment: i tried it but still did not work out...system directly boots with ubuntu 12.04...

Comment: @ izx i tried                                                sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair

Comment: You need to type all the commands in the right order. Copy-paste them in order to avoid typo. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @LovinBuntu AFTER PERFORMING BOOT REPAIR I GOT THE FOLLOWING LINK:       ---http://paste.ubuntu.com/1091318/

Answer (score 0):

According to http://paste.ubuntu.com/1091318/ you don't have any valid Windows XP installation to boot. (None of your NTFS partitions contain a /ntldr file among other things).

Probably not the answer you wanted, but if you want Windows to show up in the boot menu you need to install Windows, as currently you don't *have* any Windows installation.