# How can I get boot menu after Ubuntu installation?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I would like to thank you for taking the time to read this.

My problem: I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS on a system in my Lab but after the installation when I restarted the system it booted straight to Windows. I restarted it many times but I did not get a boot option to load Ubuntu. During the installation I do remember the installer showing that it was installing GRUB so I want to know how I can boot to Ubuntu.

The system I used has Windows 7 Enterprise edition. I created 100 GB partition (`/dev/sda6`) and a 5GB swap partition (`/dev/sda7`) before installing Ubuntu in the 100 GB partition. I chose `/dev/sda` for boot loader installation. Before installation I noticed that there already was a 26 GB ext4 partition so I am guessing that someone had previously tried installing Linux on this system. Anyway I needed more space so I carried out my installation in the 100GB partition.

I have tried all different boot orders possible in the BIOS, I have tried re-formatting and re-installing Ubuntu but it still boots into Windows directly. In windows, *System and security → System → Advanced system settings → Advanced → Startup & Recovery → Settings*:  lists Windows 7 as the default OS and doesn't give me a choice to select Ubuntu in the drop down menu.

I have tried the recommended repair in boot-repair but it gives me an error:

```
Boot repair: Please open a terminal and type this:
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" dpkg --configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub* shim-signed
```

I type them but nothing seems to happen. Then when I click the forward button I get this message:

> GRUB is still present. Please try again.

I have used Boot-repair to make a [Boot-info summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7127150/)

Please tell me how to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't comment :
 [possibly a duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182248/why-is-grub-menu-not-shown-when-starting-my-computer)

Second thing: As you have stated

> In windows, System and security>System>Advanced system
>   settings>Advanced>Startup &recovery>Settings: lists windows 7 as the
>   default OS and doesn’t give me a choice to select Ubuntu in the drop
>   down menu.

windows can't handle the ext4 file-system(Ubuntu partition) by default hence you can't access Ubuntu partition while in windows without a third-party software.