# Forgot password, locked myself out. Now unable to windows from boot

Tags: dual-boot, password

Disclaimer: Hey, I am a newbie. I am sorry if there's a mistake. Am stuck for exams by tomorrow so in a lot of rush.

I was trying to reset my password which I've forgot and reset twice before. In that pursuit I stumbled upon [this](https://client.coopnix.co.th/knowledgebase/7/Forgot-Root-Password-Give-root-password-for-maintenance-.html?rp=%2Fknowledgebase%2F7%2FForgot-Root-Password-Give-root-password-for-maintenance-.html%2F&language=english) page.

Normally the boot menu I had set up allowed me choices between the dual booted OS, between Ubuntu and windows.

I am not sure what I did, while I struck some error after which laptop started booting. Now I no longer have access to the menu, to set my choices to windows to atleast gaun access to all the data.

Please tell me this is recoverable.

Thanks

Comment: The page you linked to is for a completely different operating system …

Comment: I had no idea what I was doing. I don't know how I missed it. Can you help me how to atleast get access to the laptops bootloader menu?

Comment: If holding down the [Shift] button during the first part of the boot sequence doesn't work, you may need to [follow this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187104/1222991) to modify the Grub configuration to always show the menu.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?