# Dual boot on separate disks and esps: grub not launching and seeing windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I had a Windows installation on nvme ssd with efi partition and a clean ssd to install Ubuntu 22.04 on. I did everything as [suggested in here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds) i.e. turned off `boot` and `esp` flags on windows efi partition, then installed Ubuntu, installed gparted (for whatever reason it wasnt included), checked both flag back, run `sudo update-grub` but nothing happened after restart, it boot to ubuntu directly. Windows was installed on uefi mode. I run `sudo os-prober` and it does see windows. I also run `sudo grub-install` as it was suggested on one answer and `update` after but it didn't help also. I turned off fast boot in Windows and run `install` and `update` again, didn't help. What could be a problem? This is my disks partinoining `lsblk`:

```
sda           8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0  18,6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2        8:2    0   954M  0 part /boot
├─sda3        8:3    0   286M  0 part /boot/efi ###idk, maybe it's because I placed efi right after /boot partition when installing?
├─sda4        8:4    0  27,9G  0 part /home
└─sda5        8:5    0 185,1G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                      /
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part ### this is efi windows
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 476,3G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   533M  0 part
```

Right now if I go to `/boot` folder there's `/efi` and `/grub` folders, in `/grub` there's `grub.cfg`, but in `/efi/efi/ubuntu/` there's also `grubx64.efi` with `grub.cfg` files, is it normal? What did I miss? Any help appreciated, thanks!
Right now grub is not even launching, just straight up boots to ubuntu. `sudo grub-probe -t device /boot/grub` shows `/dev/sda2` but `sudo debconf-show grub-pc` shows empty in the line `grub-pc/install_devices` as it [said here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1119490/1502030). I also tried running `sudo grub-install dev/sda` and it didn't return any errors but also didn't help. Output of `sudo update-grub`:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after doing some research I figured out that:

1. `/efi/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg` just references `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
2. The issue was that grub wasn't detecting windows because by default now `os-prober` is not used for whatever reason.
   So in order to fix that you need to add:
   `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to `/etc/default/grub` file and then run `sudo update-grub`, after that Windows will appear and grub menu will be shown.

Comment: How do we add that line in the grub file?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, sudo vi?