# grub not showing after I deleted efi partition on HDD even though ubuntu is installed on SSD

Tags: grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I used to have 2 OS: windows 11 and ubuntu, windows was installed on my SSD and I replaced it with ubuntu, but after replacing grub was working just fine, but I tried to clean my hard drives so I deleted a efi partition on my hdd (P.S my new ubuntu is installed on SSD) I don't know what happened (I didn't touch the partitions is SSD) but grub wasn't working and I was not able to log to ubuntu, I tried to create the EFI partition again on my HDD and I formatted it as fat32 and mounted it as efi but I didn't understand what's happening, so I inserted my USB and installed ubuntu again on my ssd, now it's booting directly into ubuntu but grub isn't showing, I tried to update it and I changed the flag from hidden to menu, didn't work, and on the boot options in bios there's no option for grub, gust ubuntu and UEFI firmware and a third uefi something I don't know what it is.
when i run sudo update-grub this is what I get

[when i run sudo update-grub this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyWPj.png)

Comment: Lol, you won't beleive it, but I just solved the same problem. here you go: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1485601/dual-boot-on-separate-disks-and-esps-grub-not-launching-and-seeing-windows

Comment: But on HDD there should be working EFI parition tho

Comment: @Arzybek thanks for your help. I'm new to ubuntu can you tell me step by step instruction to what I shoud do?

Comment: Is your Windows efi working normally? Can you boot to windows?

Comment: no I deleted it, I don't want widows just linux

Comment: The ESP or *EFI System Partition* is usually found on the *first* drive as determined by BIOS or *firmware* settings, thus may **not** be on the same drive as the `/` or root partition. Your machine firmware will decide which ESP is used; thus where it needs to be located, and first drive is default for many machines. You've not said what release you're using, but your paste indicates "*os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions*" meaning other OSes won't show in grub menus due to config on your system.

Comment: @guiverc I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS release

Comment: If you want to *enable* OS-prober you can read https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/12/grub-doesnt-detect-windows-linux-distros-fix but it should be *enabled* by default if other OSes were detected during install (*it was only left disabled by default during part of the alpha stage when the article I'm providing was written, ie. well before beta or release*).  Please add the 22.04 to your question, this is a Q&A site & not a forum, readers will answer details in your question & may not read comments from others to you (*comments aren't for your replies; you can amend your question so clear*)

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.
There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments. Another problem is that your host system probably will not boot without the external device (since needed grub files are on it). If you set up an EFI partition on your SSD, you should be able to put it first in the bootorder. If SSD is not removable, it really doesn't matter which disk the EFI is on.

Comment: Have you tried running bootrepair?

Comment: @mchid no, the problem was fixed but i downloaded it now just in case, thank you

Comment: thank you @guiverc this article solved my problem

Comment: Mostly out of curiosity, but what Ubuntu ISO did you install with?  as that should not be needed for any officially released ISO (*it was a real issue when grub 2.06 was added to jammy during development, but it was resolved well prior to beta or any official release*).

Comment: @guiverc the official Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS from the website, but I think I deleted something by mistake because it was working fine when I first installed it

Comment: Thanks...  I'll assume (*for now*) the issue was a resolve of your mistake (*delete or edit; I'd expect edit*).. but regardless thank you for the reply, and Well done for solving your issue.