# Boot option menu for Ubuntu and windows with ESPs on different drives Not Showing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I've recently set up a dual boot system with Ubuntu 22.04.3 and Windows 11, installed on two separate disks. Each operating system has its own EFI System Partition (ESP) on seperate disks.

However, I'm encountering an issue where the boot menu to select the operating system doesn't appear during startup. Rightnow, I have to manually press F12 to access the boot options each time I boot my computer.

Is there a way to enable an boot menu selection for these operating systems?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to boot into your BIOS/UEFI/Firmware interface and set the machine to always boot from the disk containing Ubuntu. Booting the disk containing Windows will not give you a route to choose Ubuntu. Booting the Ubuntu disk should give you a grub menu and that should include an option to boot Windows OR Ubuntu. If it doesn’t have a Windows option there is a solution to that.

Comment: Found this discussion facing same probledm and this helped worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1485601/dual-boot-on-separate-disks-and-esps-grub-not-launching-and-seeing-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual boot on separate disks and esps: grub not launching and seeing windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1485601/dual-boot-on-separate-disks-and-esps-grub-not-launching-and-seeing-windows)