# grub menu not showing ,only boots to ubuntu 23.04 instanteously in dual boot with windows11

Tags: grub2

now i upgraded from 22.04 LTS to ubuntu 23.04 stable .after that ubuntu only boots.no grub menu displayed.No way to boot into windows.how to restore grub menu?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit grub configuration as below original post

https://askubuntu.com/a/1187104/876942

$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

I changed these two:

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden -> GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu

GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 -> GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

after changes run $ sudo update-grub

$ reboot