# How to Re-Add Windows XP to grub menu after Ubuntu 11.10 Re-install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-xp

[image]Basically, I messed up my partitions and decided to do a full re-install of both Windows XP and Ubuntu 11.10 (I know that 11.10 is outdated, but I was planning to do an update to 12.04 as soon as I got everything happened). Here is a sequence of what I did:

1. Installed Windows XP onto 20gb of hard-drive space
2. Installed Ubuntu 11.10 onto the remaining 10 gb of space using the advance setup option where I partitioned: (1gb swap, 200mb /boot, and 8.8gb / , (see screenshot))
3. Trouble struck, when I rebooted, grub2 didn't show Windows XP under my boot options.
4. I ran sudo update-grub but it still didn't find windows
5. I opened gparted and added the 'boot' flag to my windows xp partition (I was getting desperate and didn't know what to do)

And now, I'm stuck with only Ubuntu, and I don't want to have to re-install both Ubuntu and Windows to get grub working again.

Please note, I have seen [How to boot Windows XP (no GRUB menu is shown)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162878/how-to-boot-windows-xp-no-grub-menu-is-shown) and [Add windows to my boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110698/add-windows-to-my-boot-menu) but I couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks a lot,

DevNewb

Comment: The first link contains a useful link for the [Boot Info Script](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/). You should use it and let us see the results.

Comment: Ok, the results are at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6149731/

Comment: It doesn't make sense, because I did pretty much the same thing when I first installed ubuntu, but it doesn't work now...

Comment: Not sure how you've done it, but I see two problems: Windows boot files are missing, and /dev/sda is a logical partition. Pretty sure it wouldn't work in such a setup, even if you could somehow load it. Don't think you can solve it without a reinstall.

Comment: OK... I will restore the windows mbr and see if it boots, if not I'll just reinstall :P

Answer (score 1):

`boot-repair` is probably your best option. Here's how you can use it.

1. Boot into Ubuntu
2. Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot-repair`
3. Open `boot-repair`
4. Use choose the Recommended Repair
5. Follow the instructions you are given
6. Reboot once `boot-repair` is done
7. Profit!

Comment: It doesn't work because it doesn't support Ubuntu 11.10.... I need to wait till next month to download 12.04 because of my Internet package...